# How to make a list in xaml?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

```
<corelayouts:CarouselViewDots 
    BindingContext="{Binding Path=.}" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
    DotColor="White" 
    DotSize="6" 
    ScrollToIndex="{Binding ScrollToIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <corelayouts:CarouselViewDots.CarouselViews>
    <View> // There is supposed to list of view
      <citem:NewsCarouselView/>
    </View>
  </corelayouts:CarouselViewDots.CarouselViews>
</corelayouts:CarouselViewDots>
```

**How it should be processed?**
I need to take
`corelayouts:CarouselViewDots.CarouselViews`

to create a slider of View.

Comment: for what ? explain more please

Comment: I need to pass a list of slides. List<view> or list<page>

Comment: do you mean "View" inside "CarouselViews"  in list manner ?

Comment: Yes, in  class  public partial class CarouselViewDots : ContentView

Comment: I need to take this list

Comment: are you want to transfer this xml data into a list object?

Comment: Yes this list of view.

Comment: @bleggleb: Please edit your question and try to add more information. Describe what you want to do and what steps you tried, probably showing shourcecode (if any). The questions from Pranav Patel are good hints of what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlSerializer to convert XML data to class by the following manner.

```
Dim _xmlReader = New XmlTextReader("your_file.xml");

Dim _serializer = New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(your_class_type_xml_data));

Dim result = CType(_serializer.Deserialize(_xmlReader), your_class_type_xml_data);
```

Here, XmlTextReader object is used to read xml data from file.

xmlSerializer object is used to serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents.